# I am using DBeaver and go the error 'FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist'

Tags: database, sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I was using DBeaver and all of the sudden, I could no longer access my previous PostgreSQL databases or create new ones. I got the error 'FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist' when trying to open one. [image] 
I am running Windows 10, the latest version of DBeaver, and Postgres 10.6-1. I am very new to all this, all help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3):

In Database Navigator > Right click on PostgreSQL > Edit Connection

In Connection settings > general tab, enter your host (e.g. localhost), database (e.g. postgres) and leave User blank.
Check Show all databases.

Right click on PostgreSQL and refresh.
You should get a green checkmark in the PostgreSQL icon.

That's how I fixed mine, hopefully it'll work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Like Joseph, I had to leave the localhost but I had to clear all the fields, tick Show Databases:

[image]

Then refreshing on the databases I got prompted for the Username and Password (must have been an old version in cache):

[image]

This works, and you'll see there's potentially more than one schema:

[image]